# I am trying to only activate the worksheet of which the value is in a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula in worksheet 'Price History' cell E21 that changes to different worksheet names automatically depending on what other cells are equaling too. The script I have is  returning TypeError: newSheetName.getRange is not a function. In the below script i tried to copy a blank cell above E21 and paste the cell into a blank cell on the specified worksheet but that didn't help. I am trying to only activate the worksheet of which the value is in E21. Thank you

```
function MyAccount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Price History");
  var newSheetName = sheet.getRange("E21").getValue();
  sheet.getRange("E20").copyTo(newSheetName.getRange("C1"), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This line `var newSheetName = sheet.getRange("E21").getValue();` doesn't set the variable `newSheetName` as a sheet but a string value.

### SUGGESTION:

Since you have mentioned that the value of cell `E21` basically contains worksheet name that is randomly changing, perhaps you can still try using [getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename) method as this will return the sheet with the given name & then you can get the range of that sheet. See this sample tweaked script below:

***UPDATED***

```
function MyAccount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Price History");
  var newSheetName = ss.getSheetByName(sheet.getRange("E21").getValue());
  var Direction=SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
  var lastRowOfC = ss.getRange("C"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow() + 1; //Get the last row of column C on any worksheet
  sheet.getRange("E20").copyTo(newSheetName.getRange(lastRowOfC,3), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

> Getting the last row script was derived from one of the answers from [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473352) (Getting last row on a column that contains empty gaps)

### Sample test on my end:

> **NOTE**: It would also be better if you could share a sample sheet that you're using in case I have misunderstood your setup.

[image]

***UPDATED***

> **After running the script, the test cell value was copied to the destination sheet called `NewTestSheet` on the last row of column C, which is `C4`**

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I want, the line ```var newSheetName = sheet.getRange("E21").getValue();``` was throwing me off. Thank you for fixing that for me

Comment: How would i go about copying this value to the lastrow of column C, somehow make this find the last row with data in it then offset one down and paste the values?

Comment: @Hearno I have updated my answer where I have added a code to get the last row specifically on column `C` on any worksheet. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: You are the best, you respond perfectly with just what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a String value as a Sheet. Instead, use the sheet name to get a new sheet, then copy to the new range.

```
function MyAccount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Price History");
  var copyRange = sheet.getRange("E20");
  var nameRange = sheet.getRange("E21");
  copyRange.copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(nameRange.getValue()).getRange("C1"), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

Or,

```
function MyAccount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Price History");
  var copyValue = sheet.getRange("E20").getValue();
  var nameRange = sheet.getRange("E21");
  ss.getSheetByName(nameRange.getValue()).getRange("C1").setValue(copyValue);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect for me too! How would I go about getting the last row of column C and pasting the values there instead of just pasting them to only C1? Thank you

Comment: @Hearno It depends on whether or not you're expecting all of the rows to be filled.  If so, then ss.getSheetByName(nameRange.getValue()).getLastRow() will give you the last row with values in it. Otherwise, iterate down column C to find the first empty cell, then subtract 1, perhaps.

Comment: What would be the line of code to just find the last line of column C and paste the one cell at the last cell in the row of column C?

Comment: @Hearno https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column